# Code in any language (.NET preffered) to edit and create settings for PPPoE connections in Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows, windows-xp, networking

Pretty all in question... I'm looking for batch script, code or library which allows to edit and create **settings** for PPPoE connections in windows **when hardware and infrastructure is already present**. Also I'm looking for script/code to change active connection.

.NET is preffered, but any other language will do as well.

Thanks in advance

MTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be looking for code to create/modify DialUp connection or DUN(Dial Up Networking). DialUp doesn't always means the old 56kbps modem, it can also means PPPoE, PPPoA, Cable Modem and all the other possible hardware which mostly requires a login. I don't have the code, but a simple search in google with "programmatically create dialup" comes out with some example. One in [expert-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_23235781.html). 
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I think PPPOE regards to lower layer connections rather than managed code. some networking   devices exposed certain kinds of protocol like http?

Comment: i wasn't quite clear, i've added some more explanation. 
In fact this question got only general idea, cause if i knew proper keywords i would already found solution.